# why put "a" before balance?

Tags: articles

I looked up online to search the word balance.
Longman dictionary says

> EQUAL AMOUNTS [singular, uncountable] a state in which opposite forces or influences exist in equal or the correct amounts, in a way that is good
> OPP imbalance
> balance between

> Try to keep a balance between work and play.

If balance is uncountable, then why we put "a" article before balance?

Comment: Longman says 'singular, uncountable' (you copied it in your question). That means that 'balance' can be a singular (countable) noun or an uncountable one. Cambridge dictionary is clearer, using 'or' instead of a comma: `balance noun (EQUAL STATE) [ S or U ]`

Comment: For people voting to close because the answer is answerable from a dictionary, perhaps consider it is only answerable from a dictionary if you can understand what the dictionary is saying. It is useful for an English language learner to be able to request clarity on what a dictionary has told them.

Answer (score 2):

Longman says 'singular, uncountable' (you copied it in your question). In Longmans that means that 'balance' can be a singular (countable) noun or an uncountable one.

Cambridge dictionary is clearer, using S (for singular) then 'or' then U (for uncountable).

> balance noun (EQUAL STATE) [ S or U ]

[Balance (noun) Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/balance)